# How do I convert string to interger in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I have this code below and I would like to get a string like "0,0" convert to integer and sum boths variable putting it on a new variable.
I was looking for solution in internet but without sucess.

code:

```
    MouseMove, 238,282
    MouseClickDrag, Left, 238,282, 238,282
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}
    CLIPWAIT, 0.5
    SaldoContabil = %ClipBoard% ; here is getting 0,0
    Sleep, 400

    MouseMove, 602,283
    MouseClickDrag, Left, 602,283, 602,283
    Sleep, 500
    Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}
    CLIPWAIT, 0.5
    ArredAcumulado = %ClipBoard% ; here is getting 0,0
    Sleep, 400


    baixa = %ArredAcumulado% - %SaldoContabil%
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines before the final calculation.
[`StrReplace`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm) just replaces the `,` with a `.`  so from `0,0` you get `0.0`, no further conversion is necessary.

```
SaldoContabil := StrReplace(SaldoContabil,",",".")
ArredAcumulado := StrReplace(ArredAcumulado ,",",".")
```

Comment: It finally works, I was trying for two days, thanks a lot for aswer, its help me a lot.